# PDFBOX JPG image is working but PNG not working

Tags: java, image, png, pdfbox

I had print an image into 'PDF' using the following code:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/"+imageName));
PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(doc, in);
contentStream.drawXObject(img, 20, pageYaxis-120, 80, 80);
```

Here when imagName="a.jpg" its working fine, In case of imagName="b.png" its not working.  In jpg images its working but in png its not. Why it is so? Please help me. How can I make  print both the formats, I mean format in depended?

Comment: So basically, you attempted to use the function `PDJpeg` with a PNG image?

Comment: @Jongware yes dude, Wat change I need to made to make it accept PNG also??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Apache PDFBox 1.8, use PDPixelMap for PNG images:

```
BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read(new File(image));
ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, awtImage);
```

In the source code of PDFBox, see the [ImageToPDF.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/1.8/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ImageToPDF.java?view=markup&sortby=date) example. This will work with all files that can be read with ImageIO. However it is still useful to keep using PDJpeg for JPG images, because there the JPEG files are directly put into the PDF files without being converted into a lossless format.

Comment: You pressed the green symbol and you write it isn't working? What isn't working?

Comment: Is this related to the issue of not being able to convert PDF to PNG?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap alphaImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
PDImageXObject alphaXimage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, alphaImage);
```

Comment: I suspect your answer is for Android. You should mention that and mention for which version.